# Why is my callback displaying different results in .NET and Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, callback, unmanaged, managed

I'm attempting to write a script to track WIM apply progress--so far, I've been utilizing this WimgAPI wrapper example: https://managedwimgapi.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20the%20message%20callback%20functionality%20for%20recieving%20progress%20and%20other%20information&referringTitle=Documentation

Which I have converted into Powershell:

```
Add-Type -Path "Microsoft.Wim.dll"

# Open a handle to the .wim file
$wimHandle = [Microsoft.Wim.WimgApi]::CreateFile("G:\sources\boot.wim", `
    [Microsoft.Wim.WimFileAccess]::Read,[Microsoft.Wim.WimCreationDisposition]::OpenExisting, `
    [Microsoft.Wim.WimCreateFileOptions]::None, [Microsoft.Wim.WimCompressionType]::None)

# Always set temporary path
[Microsoft.Wim.WimgApi]::SetTemporaryPath($wimHandle, $env:temp) | Out-Null

# Build & register a callback method for actions which are performed by WIMGAPI for this .wim file
$callback = [Microsoft.Wim.WimMessageCallback]{
    param (
        [Microsoft.Wim.WimMessageType] $messageType,
        [System.Object] $message,
        [System.Object] $userData
    )

    if($messageType -eq [Microsoft.Wim.WimMessageType]::Progress)
    {
        $progressMessage = ($message -as [Microsoft.Wim.WimMessageProgress])
        Write-Host "Percent Complete: $($progressMessage.PercentComplete)" 
    }

    return [Microsoft.Wim.WimMessageResult]::Success
}

[Microsoft.Wim.WimgApi]::RegisterMessageCallback($wimHandle, $callback) | Out-Null

try
{
    # Get a handle to the first image in the .wim file
    $imageHandle = [Microsoft.Wim.WimgAPI]::LoadImage($wimHandle, 1)
    # Apply the contents to C:\Apply
    [Microsoft.Wim.WimgApi]::ApplyImage($imageHandle, "C:\Apply", [Microsoft.Wim.WimApplyImageOptions]::None)
    Read-Host
}
catch
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception
}
finally
{
    [Microsoft.Wim.WimgApi]::UnregisterMessageCallback($wimHandle, $callback) | Out-Null
}
```

The code executes successfully, and the WIM is applied, but unfortunately I'm only seeing the callback execute twice, like so:

```
Percent Complete: 0
Percent Complete: 100
```

Though when executing the C# application, I see every percentage value from zero to 100.

I'm thinking it may have something to do with the fact that ApplyImage is a blocking call and therefore possibly blocking the console from executing the callback, though I can't think of any way to get around this.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not.  The code is identical but I still receive inconsistent results.  I really do think it has something to do with the fact that Powershell doesn't really have a concept of threading.

Comment: thanks for replying. it is unfortunate that it doesn't work. i will dig deeper into it as it would be great to get this working given that applying a WIM image takes several minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a CmdLet in C# that will apply a `*.wim` image to location and have pushed it up to GitHub and created a Nuget package.

https://github.com/dennisroche/Microsoft.Wim.Powershell

I initially started writing the CmdLet as I was successful a quick C# demo that *was* writing the progress % to the console and thought that a CmdLet might be the solution (I had never written a CmdLet before).

In writing the CmdLet, I found out that PowerShell was throwing an `InvalidOperationException` when attempting to Write (e.g. `Write-Host`, `Write-Progress`). Looking further on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568371(v=vs.85).aspx) and I found the following:

> This method can be called only from within the implementation of an input processing method (`BeginProcessing`, `ProcessRecord`, and
>   `EndProcessing`) and only from that thread. If the call is made from
>   outside these implementations or from another thread, an
>   `InvalidOperationException` exception is thrown.

This explains why it wasn't working when called directly in Powershell - the callback was on a different thread and it had to be invoked back on the `Pipeline Execution Thread`. Though for some reason, the first and last progress events were on the `Pipeline Execution Thread`, which is why we were seeing the output that we did.

I found an interesting solution to invoking the update progress messages on the `Pipeline Execution Thread`, using the `AsyncOperationManager`, the `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`, and `Application.DoEvents()`. If you have found this answer searching the above error message, then take a look at the code on GitHub.

Comment: Good work Dennis!  Thanks for this one, it really stumped me!

Comment: Thanks @slashp. I hope you find it useful. If you're interested, I'm using this solution as part of another project - https://github.com/dennisroche/Repave

Comment: Please try out the CmdLet. Let me know if there are any issues. If you're interest open a pull request to expand to cover more uses, e.g. capture image, extract information etc, or apply specific image name (which is part done)

Comment: Dennis, I've tested your code and it works perfectly!  I have modified the code for my use case and am currently in the process of deploying it.  Once again thanks for the insight on this..if I have some time in the future I will open a pull request and add some features.